# Filter by subgroup criteria (specify the occurrence of a value per group) using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to filter a dataset and keep all groups that have exactly n rows (in my case 1 row) with a specific item.

```
df <- tibble(group=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),
        item=c(1,2,2,1,1,3))
```

I know how to filter all groups with at least 1x 1item using `any`

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(any(item==1))
```

However, I do not know if it is possible to specify the occurrence per group.
I thought about something like this:

```
filter(n(item==1)==1)
filter(any(item==1,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `group_by` `group` and calculate occurrence of `item == 1` in each group and `filter` where there are `>=` `n` occurrences.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 1

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(sum(item == 1) >= n)
```

Or using the same logic with base R `ave`

```
df[with(df, ave(item == 1, group, FUN = sum) >= n), ]
```

and for completion one with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(sum(item == 1) >= n) .SD, by = group]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` by directly subsetting

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1
setDT(df)[, .SD[sum(item == 1) >= n], by = group]
```

---

Or using `length`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(length(item[item==1]) >= n)
```